# Lasso regression get standardize and unstanderdized results

Tags: r, lasso

I' am trying to understand the steps behind the Lasso. I read several posts on the forum but I can not replicate the results.

```
mysd <- function(y) sqrt(sum((y-mean(y))^2)/length(y))
n = 500
p = 10
X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol=p)
X_sc = scale(X, scale=apply(X, 2, mysd))
b = c(.5, -.5, .25, -.25, .125, -.125, rep(0, 4))
y = X %*% b + rnorm(n, sd=.5)
y_sc = scale(y, scale = mysd(y))

#"Self standardizing"
fit = coef(glmnet(X_sc, y_sc, intercept = F, lambda = 0.1/mysd(y), thresh = 1e-12, standardize = F), s=0.1)
fit[2]*mysd(y)/mysd(X[,1])

fit = coef(glmnet(X, y, intercept = F, lambda = 0.1, thresh = 1e-12), s=0.1)
fit[2]
```

Both will reproduce different estimators. What I am doing wrong ? I took into account that I have to standardize with 1/N instead of 1/N-1 and I also scales the Lambda. I tried to solve my Problem with other threads, but I cant find a solution